# C# Speech Recognition Command Confirmation?

Tags: c#, command, speech-recognition, confirmation

So I've made the application recognize what I say. But how do I make the application confirm a request when I command it to carry out a task?

As of now I have this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecognize= new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              Choices sList = new Choices();
              sList.Add(new String[] { "Exit"});

              Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));

              sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
              sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
              sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
              sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
              sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
              sRecognize.SpeechRecognitionRejected += sRecognize_SpeechRecognitionRejected;

}

private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Result.Text == "Exit")
      {
              Application.Exit();
      }
  }
}
```

So my question as an example:

> I say, "**Exit"**

Application confirms by:

> ***Are you sure you want to exit?***

And depending on my answer, the application responds.

**Yes** being a confirmation and **No** being a request cancellation. What changes do I have to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Result.Text == "Exit")
  {
           Choices sList = new Choices();
          sList.Add(new String[] { "Yes"});

          Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));

          sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
          sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
          sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += delegate(object sender,     SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)   
                  {   
                       Application.Exit();
                  };
          sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
          sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
  }
```

}

Comment: no sir it doesn't work. It keeps comparing the speech to the initial Choice list

Comment: In Debugger it shows that It skips "recog.SpeechRecognized +=.." and goes directly to the "recog.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();"

Comment: Yeah, you need to create a new SpeechRecognitionEngine and hook up to the event on that, but not sure if it'll have implications.

Comment: Yep I did create a new Engine. Couldn't find this question tackled anywhere on the internet.

Comment: You created a new engine with the new grammar and its event still goes to the original handler?

Comment: IT WORKS! I had been checking the previous 'SpeechRecognizedEventArgs' which was named as 'e'. So I checked the new SpeechRecognizedEventArgs object which is en. Thank you!